# Redirect a URL with a query string to a specific subdomain with the same query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's the goal: 
redirect this:
http://example.com/someDir/default.aspx?Some=query
to:
http://sub.example.com/home/default.aspx?Some=query

Is this at all possible in .htaccess?  Can I do it in a WordPress environment?

Thanks for your help!

-Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes -- RedirectMatch lets you use capture groups:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /foo/bar.aspx(\?.+)? http://sub.example.com/foo/bar.aspx$1
```

Comment: Awesome.  I think it's mostly working.  Here's what I get:
If I visit this link: http://174.122.127.219/~stx/StudyTraxSites/Default.aspx?SiteName=TWERN
i should go to http://studysites.studytrax.com/home/default.aspx?SiteName=TWERN
but, instead I get a 404 error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry -- misread your first post. Please look at the edited version to see how to do this with a redirect rather than a rewrite.